# Socket getOutputStream method throws SocketException("Socket is closed") even if socket.isClosed() returns false

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a method something like this: (I use this code in android project)

```
    void flushAndClose(Socket socket,String s1){
     if (socket!=null)
         try {
             OutputStream outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
             PrintStream printStream=new PrintStream(outputStream,true);
             printStream.write(s1.getBytes());
             printStream.close(); //This only closes outputStream. Am I wrong?
             //Error will occur in inner try-catch
             //Again try catch to countinue next statement
             //Actually I call method twice so I added second try-catch just for trying it with one method.
             try {
                 System.out.println("socket.isClosed() --> "+socket.isClosed());//Returns false
                 flushAndClose(socket,s1);
             }catch (Exception e){ 
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());//"Socket is closed"
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

This is getOutputStream() method from [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java#Socket.getOutputStream%28%29)

```
825     public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
826         if (isClosed())
827             throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
828         if (!isConnected())
829             throw new SocketException("Socket is not connected");
830         if (isOutputShutdown())
831             throw new SocketException("Socket output is shutdown");
832         final Socket s = this;
833         OutputStream os = null;
834         try {
835             os = (OutputStream)
836                 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
837                     public Object More ...run() throws IOException {
838                         return impl.getOutputStream();
839                     }
840                 });
841         } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException e) {
842             throw (IOException) e.getException();
843         }
844         return os;
845     }
```

And I get s1 value once not twice. I know that calling this method `printStream.close();` in finally block will correct this problem .

But I couldn't understand that why `socket.isClosed()` returns **false** and then when I try to get second time a new instance of OutputStream class via `socket.getOutputStream();` method,this will fail even if I use same socket object which is **NOT** closed.
And return message is `SocketException() --> "Socket is closed"`

Does anyone know its cause? And I try some different combination only after invoke `socket.close();` method after that `socket.isClosed();` returns **true**

Comment: `printStream.close(); //This only closes outputStream. Am I wrong?`. Yes. You are wrong. It closes the socket too.

Comment: @greenapps So why `socket.isClosed()` returns false. And acoording to source code `826-827 lines` this just check using same method and this means it returned `true`

Comment: I dont know all those things. I only know that you should not close streams.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for quick reply.